# AWS lambda powertools Metrics only logging last metric in loop

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using [AWS Lambda Powertools Python](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/), and need to put multiple data points to a metric in my function.

Using the [Metrics](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/core/metrics/) Utility, my code looks like this

```py
from aws_lambda_powertools import Metrics
from aws_lambda_powertools.metrics import MetricUnit

metrics = Metrics()
   
@metrics.log_metrics
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # There are many things
    for thing in event["things"]:
        metrics.add_metric(
            name="MyMetric",
            unit=MetricUnit.Count,
            value=thing['value']
        )
```

Using this code, only the *final* `thing` is put to cloudwatch metrics.

How can I ensure *all* of the `things` are sent to cloudwatch metrics?

Comment: Looking for the same thing myself...Also, does the Powertools actually PUSH the metrics to Cloudwatch?  I don't see any usage of boto3 in the codebase, so are we expected to push it to CW ourselves?

Comment: I suspect you're supposed to aggregate the values yourself and if you're trying to represent the value for each thing, you'll need to have the name property be the name of the "thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming years later, note that the customer created an issue on GitHub and we added support for that use case one week later (Sep 2020).

Calling `add_metric(name="TurbineReads", value=read)` multiple times will add multiple metric data points for the metric named `TurbineReads`.

Documentation was updated back then too: https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda-python/latest/core/metrics/#adding-multi-value-metrics